# Firebase auth login limit with an unique account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I love firebase.

I'm building a android app where customers have to login with a unique account credential (email/password) provided by an admin.

Is there any limit for multiple connections by the same account at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for loving Firebase.

There are no inherent restrictions on how many connections a user may have with any of the Firebase products.